# Can you make a DIY UAF42 universal filter using op amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit

I am wondering if its possible to make a DIY UAF42 universal filter.

I know if I get a circuit diagram of the internals of the UAF42 and put it into a spice program using ideal op amps it does actually work if I put the correct external resistors to make a filter.

I know that it might be possible if I can get op amps that have similar specs as the internal op amps in this IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.  It's just a state-variable filter and you can put it together with discrete op-amps.  Of course performance will depend on the specs of the op-amps you choose, and how you put them together (layout, etc.).  But it's certainly possible.